# JSF2 jQuery during window load

Tags: jquery, jsf-2

Trying to invoke jQuery from JSF2 (Mojarra).During window load trying to display the alert mesage.But not sure on how to invoke the jquery functionality.

Any help appreciated.

Here follows the code snippet of js(test.js)

```
$(window).load(function() {
 alert('window load occurred!');    
});
```

XHTML code follows here

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:outputScript library="js" name="test.js" target="head" />
<h:body>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first should include the jquery js library itself

add

```
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or download it and load it from local just like you  load your test.js

```
<h:outputScript name="js\jquery.min.js" target="head" />
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have downloaded the jquery-1.7.2.min.js and as suggested added this into xhtml page.But still no hopes.